# Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'result' property from 'IDBRequest': The request has not finished

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I need your help guys.

I am using `indexedDB`. I need to read records from a table in the DB using `Javascript` but I am getting an error message that says from Chrome browser V52 **Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'result' property from 'IDBRequest': The request has not finished.**

Below is my Javascript code

var db;
        var availableJobs = 0;

```
    window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;

    var request = window.indexedDB.open("MyDbName", 1);

    request.onsuccess = function (event) {
        db = request.result;
    }

    request.onblocked = function (event) {
        db = "blocked...";
    };

    request.onerror = function (event) {
        db = "Error...";

    };

    var objectStore = db.transaction("ActionCard").objectStore("ActionCard");

    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function (event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;

        if (cursor) {
            if (cursor.value.ActionCardStatusId == 1 || cursor.value.ActionCardStatusId == 3) {
                availableJobs++;
            }

            cursor.continue();
        }

        $("#availableJobs").html(availableJobs);
    }
```

I am getting an error message on this line

```
var objectStore = db.transaction("ActionCard").objectStore("ActionCard");
```

Comment: It sees like the variable `db` is always `null` even though I am assigning a value to it in the `onsuccess` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to learn about how to write asynchronous Javascript. Your db variable isn't defined at the time you access it.

Don't do this:

```
var r = indexedDB.open();
var db = null;
r.onsuccess = function(event) { db = event.target.result); }
```

Do this:

```
var r = indexedDB.open();
r.onsuccess = function(event) {
  var db = event.target.result;
};
```

And yes, that means db isn't available outside the scope of the onsuccess function. Stop trying to use it outside its scope or you will just run into the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: If I'm writing the method like this `r.onsuccess = (event) => {
  var db = event.target.result;
};` wouldn't then the event be accessible outside the scope once loaded?

Comment: accessible but undefined if you want to pedantic. i am trying to give a simplified answer that avoids the problem that happens because someone does not understand asynchronous code.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign db like this and use it outside like you wanted or in functions for add/put or get or for removing from the IndexedDB. The below is sample piece.

```
var db;
var request = window.indexedDB.open("db_name", 1);

request.onupgradeneeded = function() {
    var db = request.result;
    var storeName = db.createObjectStore("storeName", {keyPath: "keyAttribute"});
    storeName.createIndex("testIndex", "testCase", { unique: false });
};
request.onerror = function(event) {
  // Do something with request.errorCode!
  console.log("failed opening DB: "+request.errorCode)
};
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  // Do something with request.result!
  db = request.result;
  console.log("opened DB")
};

//Adding function - can pass values as function params
function addData(objectStoreName){
    // Start a new transaction
    var transaction = db.transaction(objectStoreName, "readwrite");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(objectStoreName);
    // Add some data
    var request = objectStore.put({testCase: 'ddi',timestamp: performance.now(), name: "testname2", data: 'asdsadas'});
        request.onsuccess = function(event) {
            // event.target.result === customer.ssn;
            console.log("request.onsuccess: "+event.target.result);
        };
        request.onerror = function(event) {
            // event.target.result === customer.ssn;
            console.log("request.onerror: "+request.errorCode);
    };
    transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
      console.log("All added to "+objectStore+"!");
    };
    transaction.onerror = function(event) {
      // Don't forget to handle errors!
      console.log("Error in adding data to "+objectStore+"!");
    };
}


function getData(objectStoreName){
    // Start a new transaction
    var transaction = db.transaction(objectStoreName, "readwrite");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(objectStoreName);
    var index = objectStore.index("TestCaseIndex");
    // Query the data
    var getDDIData = index.get("ddi");
    getDDIData.onsuccess = function() {
        console.log(getDDIData.result);
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi, to get the data you don't need to pass "readwrite".

Comment: @R.Calhau, Yeah.. Looks like you are right. Can you edit my answer? I cant test as I have left the project.